# What's the meaning of "Bien sûr je veux mon palais mais racontez pas vos salades"

Tags: sens, expressions, traduction, vocabulaire, expressions-idiomatiques

I cannot understand what the meaning of "*Bien sûr je veux mon palais mais racontez pas vos salades*" is.

I could not understand the first part of the phrase because I know that "*raconter des salades*" means "*to tell lies or spin yarns*".

Comment: It could mean both imo, lie and spin yarns, having the full context would help to determine.

Comment: Hi Zuko and welcome to French SE! Please provide some context to the sentence you are trying to understand (what was the person doing when they said it for example, and what sentences were said before this one), it will make it easier for us to help you. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

> *Bien sûr, je veux mon palais*

just means

> of course, I want my own palace

There is no specific clue about this palace in [the song where this sentence appears](https://greatsong.net/paroles-rodeo-eva) so I guess it just means that Mounir Kidadi wants to be wealthy enough to own a palatial home.

Comment: thank you......