# The difference between "avoir intérêt que" & "avoir intérêt à "

Tags: grammaire, sens, expressions, traduction, vocabulaire

I want to know the difference & the meaning of "v.avoir+intérêt+que" & "v.avoir+intérêt+à"
and what's the meaning of 
" J'avais intérêt que j'y arrive "
and thanks

Answer (score 4):

*Avoir intérêt que* is hurting so much French ears that most native people consider it incorrect and promote the usual *avoir intérêt à ce que*. Actually, when followed by a subjunctive, the form *avoir intérêt que* does exist but is very formal and literary.

As your sentence is relating something happening in the past, that might have even read:

> *J'avais intérêt que j'y arrivasse.*

but nobody talks or writes that way nowadays.

The meaning is something like:

> Making it was my best interest.

or

> I had better make it.

As you wrote in a comment that you heard it from a song, I realized it's in [the same one](https://greatsong.net/paroles-rodeo-eva) you already referred to in [another question](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/41855/1109). The singer indeed says:

> *J'ai fait six millions de vues, je sais mais bon j'avais intérêt qu'j'y arrive.*

which is very colloquial and has the same meaning (I'd better make it).

It's interesting to see that *avoir intérêt que* can be very informal or very formal, but not in between.

Here are some of the few occurrences of the formal "*avoir intérêt que*" form:

> *Mais comme chaque peuplade avait intérêt que son capitaine fût le meilleur, elle avait intérêt aussi à croire, et par conséquent elle croyait que son dieu était le plus puissant.* Voltaire, *Dictionnaire philosophique*, 1764.
>
> *Trop de gens ont intérêt qu'ils [les princes] ne sachent pas la vérité tout entière* Bossuet, 1836
>
> *Qui donc avait intérêt que l'on arrêtât ces messes clandestines ?*, Florence Baudeneau, *Faits divers*, 2018.

Références:

- Grevisse, La préposition: Règles, exercices et corrigés.
- [Littré](https://www.littre.org/definition/int%C3%A9r%C3%AAt)

  > <sub>Avoir intérêt que, avec un verbe au subjonctif.
  >
  > Trop de gens ont intérêt qu'ils [les princes] ne sachent pas la vérité tout entière, Bossuet, Polit. VIII, IV, 4.
  >
  > De s'entêter qu'elle [une chose] est, parce qu'on veut qu'elle soit ; de la contredire avec obstination parce qu'on a intérêt qu'elle ne soit pas, Bourdaloue, Carême, III, Paix chrét.</sub>
- http://parler-francais.eklablog.com/des-avoir-s-et-des-interets-a118210160 :

  > <sub>Remarque 3 : Selon Girodet, « dans la langue très soignée, on évitera le tour avoir intérêt à ce que et on préférera avoir intérêt que (suivi du subjonctif) : Nous avons intérêt que cet accord soit signé rapidement (plutôt que à ce que cet accord soit signé). »</sub>

Comment: thank you ..so much for your help

Answer (score 1):

"avoir intérêt que" is not french. Where you read/hear that ?

"J'avais intérêt que j'y arrive" -> "J'avais intérêt d'y arriver" or "J'avais intérêt à y arriver" depend of the context, but the original sentence is not correct in French, so complicated to translate correctly

Comment: Note that *Avoir intérêt à ce que* exists. Ex: tu as intérêt à ce qu'ill y arrive.

Comment: Yes I agree, but "avoir intérêt à ce que" and "avoir intérêt que" it's not the same :)

Comment: i didn't translate it..i got it from a song but i didn't understand the meaning because i know that "Avoir intérêt " takes "à" not "que" and i made a lot of researches but i didn't find any thing so that's why i asked here

Comment: *Avoir intérêt à ce que* and *avoir intérêt que* are actually the same expression but with different language registers.